# flex buttonbar initially anything selected flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark, buttonbar

hello i have this buttonbar:

```
<s:ButtonBar id="channelsBtnBar" requireSelection="true" width="100%" horizontalCenter="0"
                     skinClass="skins.TvButtonBarSkin"
                     change="channelsBtnBar_changeHandler(event)"> 
            <s:dataProvider>
                <s:ArrayList>
                    <fx:Object icon="@Embed('assets/ch1.png')"/>
                    <fx:Object icon="@Embed('assets/ch2.png')"/>
                    <fx:Object icon="@Embed('assets/ch3.png')"/>
                    <fx:Object icon="@Embed('assets/ch4.png')"/>
                    <fx:Object icon="@Embed('assets/ch5.png')"/>
                    <fx:Object icon="@Embed('assets/ch6.png')"/>
                    <fx:Object icon="@Embed('assets/ch7.png')"/>
                    <fx:Object icon="@Embed('assets/ch8.png')"/>
                    <fx:Object icon="@Embed('assets/ch9.png')"/>
                </s:ArrayList>
            </s:dataProvider>

</s:ButtonBar>
```

how can i have in creationcomplete of the parent component any of the items selected? is this possible without setting requireSelection to false and selectedItem to -1?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.  Do you want to default the buttonBar to a "nothing selected" state?

Comment: yes exactly but with requireSelection="true"... if i set selectedItem="-1" does not work..any idea?

Comment: Isn't that expected behaviour?  If you want to require a selection, why would you be able to put it in the "nothing selected" state?

Comment: before the user clicks anywhere on the buttonbar i want nothing selected but this behaviour to start at the first click..i think i solved it right know..should i change the property to true at the first click?:)

Comment: That seems reasonable.  Swap the property on first click.

Answer (score 1):

Swap the property requireSelection to "true" on first click!

Answer (score 0):

Use selectedIndex property of ButtonBar.

if you want to select any item use selectedIndex="2" where as 2 is your selected index of ButtonBar.
If you do not want to select any thing use selectedIndex="-1".

Hope this may help....

Comment: FYI, "requireSelection" Property Description: - If true, a data item must always be selected in the control. If the value is true, the selectedIndex property is always set to a value between 0 and (dataProvider.length - 1). 
The default value is false for most subclasses, except TabBar. In that case, the default is true.